# API Search query python 3.5

Tags: python, json

I am able to print a json file that I pulled using an API, however I am stuck in being able to make search query out of it or being able to only print specific pieces of data from it. The api is for PGA Tour player Bios. How can I print just one piece of information from the Json string or dictionary? I tried searching in here and couldn't find anything clear that would allow me to print just one specific piece of data such as "Jason Day" Thank you very much.

```
import http.client

import json

import urllib.parse

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sportradar.us")

conn.request("GET", "/golf-t2/changelog/pga/2017/2/21/changes.json?api_key=8vdpch88ce829q4u7najdjcg")

res = conn.getresponse()

data = res.read()

data2 = (data.decode("utf-8"))

print(data2)
```

Comment: Use the `requests` library. Their [homepage](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) has an example of what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to json :

```
import http.client

import json

import urllib.parse

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sportradar.us")

conn.request("GET", "/golf-t2/changelog/pga/2017/2/21/changes.json?api_key=8vdpch88ce829q4u7najdjcg")

res = conn.getresponse()

data = res.read()

data2 = json.loads((data.decode("utf-8")))

print(data2["id"])
```

if you want to find if something is in the json simply use:
`something  in data2`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. as far as what i can put in for ["id"] i should be able to find in the Api documentation?

Comment: yes you need to read the docs or make a for loop and print all the keys...

Comment: http://api.sportradar.us/golf-t2/summary/pga/2017/tournaments/6180b261-9595-4b90-a706-58f54258da71/summary.json?api_key=8vdpch88ce829q4u7najdjcg          
Above is the api: 
Print(data2[‘venue’]
It returns something like this…
:{"id":"6c5fd917-3708-4560-bd3d-f7b060b13e93","name":"Colonial CC","city":"Fort [{"name":"Colonial Country Club","yardage":7204,"par":70,"id":"756588be-366c-49ef-ae3c-bf129b785e2b","holes":[{"number":1,"par":5,"yardage":565},{"number":2,"par":4,"yardage":389},
How would I be able to print just “number 2 par 4 yardage 389”?
tyvm